# Canvas professional drawing effects

Tags: html, canvas, drawing

Recently I've been learning HTML5 stuff, especially *canvas*.
I looked at many online drawing applications written in Flash(e.g. http://www.sumopaint.com, http://www.onemotion.com/flash/sketch-paint/) and they all seem packaged with awesome drawing effects. Smooth lines, simulated pencil/brush etc.

What I'd like to know is - is there a way to get such effects in *canvas*, and how?
I'm willing to put 1 month of (free-time)coding work to do it, but I'm not sure if it's even feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Canvaspaint.org](http://canvaspaint.org) is an early now-public-domain project along these lines; the source is available [here](http://canvaspaint.org/paint.js). [Here](http://mrdoob.com/projects/harmony/) ([source](http://github.com/mrdoob/harmony)) and [here](http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/) and are more recent interesting projects.

Comment: Sigh... it's not nearly the same. One is - literally - paint, the other is nearly Photoshop. Still, thanks for the answer.